# Problema al ingresar valores a campo TextField de Material Ui en NextJs, no funciona cuando onchange = setState

Tags: typescript, material-ui, next.js, textfield

Soy algo nuevo en material ui y nextjs y tengo el siguiente problema:

Cuando le agrego a la propiedad onChange de mi TextField la funcion setState para controlar el evento para que asi pueda trabajar el valor ingresado, el input deja de funcionar y no tipea valores

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
const [age, setAge] = useState<number[]>([0, 100]);

<TextField
        label="Edad max"
        type="number"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{ width: '8rem' }}
        value={age[1]}
        onChange={(event) => setAge([age[0], parseInt(event.target.value, 10)])}
      />
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar. El problema era que el input TextField estaba dentro de un componente hijo que había sido desarrollado dentro del componente padre pero la declaracion de estados para las variables estaba en este componente pero no eran pasadas como props al componente hijo, por lo que había un cortocircuito en el evento on change y me quitaba el focus del input. Es una mala práctica aparentemente desarrollador componentes hijos dentro de los padres. Genera problemas de rendimiento y de scope. LA SOLUCIÓN? Simple, separar los componentes y declarar las variables con sus estados (solo las que van a ser repartidas por los hijos) dentro del padre y pasarlas como props a los componentes hijos. La siguiente pregunta con su solución ahonda un poco mas en el tema del pase de variables y estados entre componentes padres e hijos:
[Enviar datos de componente Hijo a Padre (React JS)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466976/enviar-datos-de-componente-hijo-a-padre-react-js)

Aquí un artículo en inglés sobre porque no es buena práctica desarrollar componentes dentro de otros:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-review-avoid-declaring-react-component-inside-parent-component-1768a645f523